# Eclipse Android AVD Emulator Does Not Display Buttons for Custom Resolution Skin

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

When I create an AVD in the Android Eclipse environment, if I choose under "skin" a built in slection, when the avd runs, I get buttons to the right. If I select a custom resolution and enter any height an width, I just get the screen and no buttons in the emulator. How can I create a custom AVD with a custom height and width that show the buttons on the right?

Comment: you should post your xml

Comment: This is not about content of the application, it's about AVD itself - what xml are you asking for?

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with the app. This is about creating an AVD. If I used the built in skins, the AVD shows button to the right of the AVD screen. If I use a custom resolution, only the screen shows with no buttons making it impossible to test the app in the AVD. How can I get a custom resolution AVD with the buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just experienced the same situation. I didn't manage to show a keyboard, but a colleague of mine advised to just [use shortcuts](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#KeyMapping)

**Shortcuts:**

```
Emulated Device Key                   - Keyboard Key
Home                                  - HOME
Menu (left softkey)                   - F2 or Page-up button
Star (right softkey)                  - Shift-F2 or Page Down
Back                                  - ESC
Call/dial button                      - F3
Hangup/end call button                - F4
Search                                - F5
Power button                          - F7
Audio volume up button                - KEYPAD_PLUS, Ctrl-F5
Audio volume down button              - KEYPAD_MINUS, Ctrl-F6
Camera button                         - Ctrl-KEYPAD_5, Ctrl-F3
Switch to previous layout orientation - KEYPAD_7, Ctrl-F11
(for example, portrait, landscape)
Switch to next layout orientation     - KEYPAD_9, Ctrl-F12
(for example, portrait, landscape)
Toggle cell networking on/off         - F8
Toggle code profiling                 - F9 (only with -trace startup option)
Toggle fullscreen mode                - Alt-Enter
Toggle trackball mode                 - F6
Enter trackball mode temporarily      - Delete
(while key is pressed)
DPad left/up/right/down               - KEYPAD_4/8/6/2
DPad center click                     - KEYPAD_5
Onion alpha increase/decrease         - KEYPAD_MULTIPLY(*) / KEYPAD_DIVIDE(/)
```